# Custom pageradapter class getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

My custom `pageadapter` is getting `NullPointerException` at `instantiateItem`. However, if I use this adapter as an inner-class then there is no error.

My custom pageadapter class

```
class MyPagesAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    String mPageData[]; //Stores the text to swipe.
    LayoutInflater inflater;    //Used to create individual pages
    ViewPager vp;

    public MyPagesAdapter(String pageData[])
    {
        mPageData = pageData;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPageData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
        ((TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.textMessage)).setText(mPageData[position]);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(page, 0);
        return page;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {

        return arg0==(View)arg1;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
      object=null;
    }
}
```

Here is mainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String pageData[];  //Stores the text to swipe.
LayoutInflater inflater;    //Used to create individual pages
ViewPager vp;   //Reference

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pageData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desserts);
    //get an inflater to be used to create single pages
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //Reference ViewPager defined in activity
    vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    //set the adapter that will create the individual pages
    vp.setAdapter(new MyPagesAdapter(pageData));
}}
```

Here is Error:

```
    07-03 10:02:07.269: D/dalvikvm(1391): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-03 10:02:07.289: D/AndroidRuntime(1391): Shutting down VM
07-03 10:02:07.289: W/dalvikvm(1391): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5004180)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.example.viewpager2.MyPagesAdapter.instantiateItem(MyPagesAdapter.java:30)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:869)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1019)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-03 10:02:07.339: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 10:02:07.780: I/dalvikvm(1391): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-03 10:02:07.780: I/dalvikvm(1391): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-03 10:02:07.958: I/dalvikvm(1391): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-03 10:02:07.958: I/dalvikvm(1391): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Update:

one solution could be passing the inflater to pageadapter class from activity

```
vp.setAdapter(new MyPagesAdapter(pageData,inflater));
```

in pageadapter class

```
public MyPagesAdapter(String pageData[], LayoutInflater minflater)
    {
        mPageData = pageData;
        inflater = minflater;
    }
```

or simply stablish Layoutinflater in pageadapter class

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: it seems exception is thrown because of inflatter you are declaring it in activity but not in PagerAdapter

Comment: @mohammadsadeghsaati The inflater he declared in the Activity is not used anywhere as far as I can see and I don't think that's the cause of the exception.

Comment: inflater in adapter is null ???

Comment: Thanks @mohammad sadegh saati. I just have to pass inflater to adapter from activity :)

Comment: You don't need to pass that. you can use `LayoutInflater.from()` method